# Setting up Amazon Elastic Beanstalk app without public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have an internal network that is connected to our vpc through a vpn connection. 
We use only private IPs to get around, and the VPC has a NAT for internet access for our instance. We try to not to have an any public IP on our instances.

I love the ease of deploying to beanstalk, So I've been trying really hard to use it as a single-instance not load balancing.

However no matter what I do it forces me to have a public dns and public elastic IP, even if you unclick 'Associate Public IP Address' 
Whats Worse is, It doesn't even let me disassociate it manually, Just keeps adding it back on.

Is there anyway to use beanstalk ONLY inside your VPC and not give it a public address??
If No, why the heck not?

Comment: Are you deploying to a public or private VPC subnet? Are you deploying a single-instance or load-balanced EB application?

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/698007/launch-instances-via-elastic-beanstalk-without-elastic-ip-configured

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't possible to do using Single Instance configuration.  The work around was using the load balancer, selecting visibility internal, and then when the Environment is built, Terminate the load balancer. It will then be a single instance, and not have a public IP;

Edit:
So the Load Balancer will eventually add itself back.

Also to note: if you remove the beanstalk security group from your instance and add a security group that doesn't allow access from the ELB, The ENV in beanstalk will look red but it will work fine.
but if The ENV is red for over 2 weeks, beanstalk automatically terminates the instance, Rebuilding ENV will not work afterwards.

There is currently no way to deploy a single instance without a public IP using elastic Beanstalk short of maybe writing a lambda script that strips the elastic ip ever minute.

[UPDATE:::]

**If you disassociate the EIP you have about 5 seconds to release it,if you do it will not be reattached. it with will not cause the env to terminate and will be gone forever.** YAY (untill you rebuild)

Comment: but when I try to 'eb deploy' the deploy got stuck because the EIP does not exists.

Comment: If the instance is in a public subnet there's no way to talk to talk to it without a public IP

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the tutorial [Example: Launching an Elastic Beanstalk in a VPC with Amazon RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html)? Specifically, check the `ELB visibility` configuration and make sure that is set to `Internal`.

Copied from [Deploying with the Elastic Beanstalk Console](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html#vpc-rds-new-console):

> **ELB visibility**
>
> Select `External` if your load balancer should be publicly available, or select `Internal` if the load balancer should only be available within your VPC.

Please study the rest of the tutorial for more details.

Comment: Could I make a EB with single instance as Internal VPC Service ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  First create a custom private subnet before you create your beanstalk environment.  Then as you create your environment, select the private subnet you just created.  Then leave the Activate Public IP unchecked.

For security purposes, this is preferrable.  Your instance shouldn't be publicly accessible over the internet.

NOTE: If you put your environment in a public subnet, you're not going to be able to switch off the public IP.  That makes sense because, well, you're in a public subnet.